# error placement in jquery validation for dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Probably something asked a hundred times however i can't find what i'm looking for...
So, as said in the title, i'd like to display an error in a div using jquery validation plugin; the form is generated dynamically; i think i got more or less that part doing a each loop to select the activated form... but i cant figure out how to display the error in the wanted div (in the code below, the div with "errors" as id)... thanks in advance!!!

html code

```
<form class="addCardForm" action="card/add" method="post">
      <input class='column_id' type='text' name='column_id' value='<?= $column->get_id() ?>' hidden>
      <input type="text" name="title" id='title<?= $column->get_id() ?>' placeholder="Add a card">
      <input type="submit" value="&#xf067" class="fas fa-plus">
</form>
<div id="errors<?= $column->get_id() ?>"></div>
```

jquery validation

```
$(".addCardForm").each(function() {
        const $form = $(this).validate({
            rules: {
                title: {
                    remote: {
                        url: "card/card_title_exists_service/",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            column_id: function() {
                                return $(".column_id").val()
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    minlength: 3

                }
            },

            messages: {
                title: {
                    remote: "A card with the same title already exists",
                    minlength: "Title must be at least 3 characters long"
                }
            },
            errorLabelContainer: $(this).closest("[id^='errors']")
        });
    });
```

what i have in the html while running

```
<form class="add add_card addCardForm" action="card/add" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
      <input class="column_id" type="text" name="column_id" value="16" hidden="">
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title16" placeholder="Add a card" class="error" aria-invalid="true">
      <label id="title16-error" class="error" for="title16">Title must be at least 3 characters long</label>
      <input type="submit" value="" class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">
</form>
<div id="errors16></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this.

```
function validate() {
  var form = $('.addCardForm');
     form.validate({
         ignore: [],
         rules: {
            column_id: {
                required: true,
            },
         },
         highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
             .parents('div').addClass('has-error') // set error class to the control group
         },
        unhighlight: function (element) { // un-hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
              .parents('div').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.siblings('.error-msg'));
        },
    });
    $('input[name^="title"]').filter('input[name$="value"]').each(function() {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            // add your rules here.
            required: true,
            messages: {
               required: 'Youre message here.'
            }
        });
   });
```

Comment: i still cannot target the div to write the message in

Comment: just an evolution... maybe not entierely positive ;-)) if i change errorLabelContainer to errorLabelContainer: $(this).parent(["id^='errors'"]) i target the div (or i have something very similar to what i expect); however, when the input is corrected, the form disapears !!!

Comment: okay... i got it... errorLabelContainer: $(this).siblings(["id^='cardError'"])

Comment: you put me on the right track... thanks a lot!

Comment: @DenisCapece you're welcome. And it's my pleasure if it works for you.